# Why isn't my WebMethod being called from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods

I'm working in ASP.Net 4. I have the following within the body tag of my aspx:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"/> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function Process() {
          var CHK = document.getElementById("<%=lstAffEmployees.ClientID%>");
          var checkbox = CHK.getElementsByTagName("input");
          var counter = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
              if (checkbox[i].checked) {
                  counter++;
                  var Attorney = label[i].innerHTML;
                  var cutoff = Attorney.indexOf('[');
                  var cAttorney = Attorney.substring(0, cutoff - 1);
                  PageMethods.saveData(checkbox[i].value, cAttorney);
                  
              }
              
          }
          return true;
      }
</script>
```

In my code-behind, I have:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void saveData(string attyNo, string attyName)
    {
        //mycode
    }
```

In debugging, I get to the PageMethods call in the javascript, but then saveData in my code-behind is never called. I don't understand why not. Can anyone help?

Comment: When you're using your JS debugger, what happens inside `PageMethods.saveData` ? What do you see in your browser's dev-tool's Network activity tab? Does it work in Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: Also, you need to tidy up your code: you're mixing `camelCase` and `PascalCase` for locals, ew.. And you're using singular names like `checkbox` for collections (`var checkbox` will have a runtime type of `NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement>`, not a singular `HTMLInputElement`).

Comment: It doesn't work in IE 11. When I use the JS debugger, it doesn't show me a whole lot. It goes to a saveData function in the browser's javascript, but doesn't give an error, and it never hits the breakpoint I have on the saveData code behind function.